# Totient function in arithmetic progressions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $c=m\cdot n$, positive integers. It is well known that $\varphi(c)$ counts the number of elements $i$ such that  and $1\leq i\leq c$ and $\gcd(i,c)=1$. But what if instead of the whole set $C=\{1,2,...,c\}$ one would consider the set $C_1=\{1,1+n,1+2n,...,1+(m-1)n\}$  or$C_a=\{a,a+n,a+2n,...,a+(m-1)n\}$ (with $1\leq a \leq n$)? Is there any relation known between the number of elements in $C_a$  that are coprime with $c$, and $\varphi(c)$?

I'm asking this because of the following examples:

1. Let $c=2280=19\cdot 12\cdot 10$ (note that $19\cdot 12=228,12=11+1,10=11-1$).  The elements of the set $\{1,229,457,685,913,1141,1369,1597,1825,2053\}$
   are in an arithmetic progression such that the difference between consecutive terms is $228$. Of these $10$ elements, $8$ are coprime with $2280$. And we have $\frac{\varphi(2280)}{\varphi(228)}=\frac{576}{72}=8$.
2. Let $c=4368=7\cdot 26\cdot 24$ (note that $7\cdot 26=182,26=25+1,24=25-1$).  The $24$ elements of the set $\{1,183,365,...,3823,4005,4187\}$
   are in an arithmetic progression such that the difference between consecutive terms is $182$. Of these $24$ elements, $16$ are coprime with $4368$. And we have $\frac{\varphi(4368)}{\varphi(182)}=\frac{1152}{72}=16$.
3. Let $c=7200=3\cdot 50\cdot 48$ (note that $3\cdot 50=150,50=49+1,48=49-1$).  The $48$ elements of the set $\{1,151,301,...,6751,6901,7051\}$
   are in an arithmetic progression such that the difference between consecutive terms is $150$. Of these $48$ elements, all of them are coprime with $7200$. And we have $\frac{\varphi(7200)}{\varphi(150)}=\frac{1920}{40}=48.$

So if  $c=e(p^i+1)(p^i-1)$ with $p$ prime and $e$ coprime with $p^i+1$ (actually the definition of $e$ is a little more complicated) it looks that the number of elements that belong to $\{1,1+e(p^i+1),1+2e(p^i+1),...,1+(p^i-2)e(p^i+1)\}$ coprime with $c$ are given by $\frac{\varphi(c)}{\varphi(e(p^i+1))}$ . I haven't been able to prove this. What do you think of it?